# ASP.NET Windows Authentication with Custom Roles

Tags: asp.net

If I am using Windows Authentication in an ASP.NET app, and I want to use custom roles instead of using Windows security groups as roles, do I need to write a custom Role provider?  The solution needs to be able to map Windows users and groups to application specific roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question - no you don't need to use roles from Active Directory security groups as roles for your ASP.NET application.  And you dont need to implement a custom Role provider.  The default one simply retrieves the Roles from the ASP.NET application database.

You can simply have application defined roles in this database, that you create with the `aspnet_regsql.exe` utility (in the .NET 2.0 framework folder).

Probably the greatest collections of resources/information on this topic:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership_2C00_-Roles_2C00_-Forms-Authentication_2C00_-and-Security-Resources-.aspx

Comment: I just tested mapping Windows accounts to roles using the SQL role provider and it seems to work.  Except I can't seem to use the built in ASP.NET security configuration web site to configure it because that seems to be tied to forms auth (meaning I have to create a tool for managing roles).  Still, this is a good approach I think.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you CAN use the built in `ASP.NET` security configuration web site. You have to temporarily switch to Internet Mode, Then you can add users `DOMAIN\username` as username, enter some password (it won't be used once you switch back), you can then assign these to roles. Once you switch back to Windows mode these users will be used automatically.

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't let me "add comment" to the existing answer.