# manually adding users to roles in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have googled the heck out of this and i cannot find a solution. i would like to add users to a role manually using the administration tool or just manually doing this. i am a beginner with asp.net, how would i do this? i am using windows authentication

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922202/asp-net-windows-authentication-with-custom-roles

Comment: please see image here, i have no users: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/20/77086680.png/ to choose from

Comment: @tomas do you have an answer please

Comment: do i need to use windows security group as role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using ASP.NET authentication**

- open website administration tool .
- click on security. click manage users.
- click on edit role beside the username and you will see a list of available roles.
  [image]

if you can't find any users then you have to choose create user first.
if you can't find any roles then go back to security and click enable roles then create new role first and repeat the above steps after complition.

for windows authentication you can check for a certain user in code as follow

•Use the IPrincipal interface of the User object attached to the current HTTP request.

if(User.IsInRole(@"DomainName\Manager"))
  // Perform restricted operation
else
  // Return unauthorized access error.

but any group managment mut be done using windows managment (users and groups) 
for more info.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx

Comment: it is windows authentication - do i still need to create users? we already have hundreds of users on our domain controller

Comment: in windows authentication you can only check to see if a current user isInRole = some group in windows to create a role or chenge it or add  users to it you have to do this using windows management or active directory

Comment: can you help with this please http://serverfault.com/questions/304166/does-iis-server-have-to-be-on-domain-for-windows-authentication-and-roles

Comment: plz check the msdn link above for full coverage on this subject .

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio as and IDE. Click `Project` Tab and select `ASP.NET Configuration`. From there click `Security` to manage accounts and roles.

Comment: please see image here, i have no users: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/20/77086680.png/ to choose from

Comment: So what is the problem ? You normally have users but they do not appear here ? or you don't know how to create users ?

Comment: please help with this http://serverfault.com/questions/304166/does-iis-server-have-to-be-on-domain-for-windows-authentication-and-roles